# How to get vpc id of sagemaker instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to find the notebook's VPC id by using the boto3 sagemaker client, however, I'm not finding where this data is in the client.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The [describe_domain()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_domain) method will return the Notebook VPC ID.

Here's an example code snippet using this method:

```
import boto3

region = boto3.Session().region_name
client = boto3.Session().client("sagemaker")

vpc_id = client.describe_domain(
    DomainId=client.list_domains()["Domains"][0].get("DomainId")
).get("VpcId")

print(vpc_id)
```